# Why the distribution network have 4 wires ( not neutral)?

Tags: power, transmission-line, system

In a real network the distribution lines were 3 lines (ABC). At one pole the lines became 4 lines which are ( ABBC) the phase B split to two lines . Could you please illustrate why they split them to ABBC configuration.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In some rare situations, a Delta 240 3ph will use one to create two split phase 120Vac outputs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6aFgv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>